# Codename One stop() method: why don't we keep Dialog?

Tags: codenameone

The default Codename One method is:

```
public void stop() {
        current = getCurrentForm();
        if (current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog) current).dispose();
            current = getCurrentForm();
        }
    }
```

Is it really necessary to dispose a Dialog? Why?
Advantages and disadvantages of eliminating the Dialog related code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start()` is invoked to restore the app. So if it's minimized `stop()` will be invoked and dispose the dialog. Let's say it doesn't do that... `start()` will be invoked again and dialog will be shown again.

The `show()` method of dialog is blocking. So it will stop the current callback in its tracks and effectively botch the whole restore process.

As an alternative we tried in the past to check if this is a dialog on restore and use `showModless()` but this has issues with some port code that also invokes `show()` on the current `Form`. The only solution that might work is to save the dialog instance as a special case and dispose it. Then re-show it with a `callSerially()` in `start()`.

Comment: Unfortunately «[...] to save the dialog instance as a special case and dispose it. Then re-show it with a callSerially() in start()» works only in the Simulator and on Android, but it doesn't work on iPhone. I tried to show again the Dialog even with a UITimer after showing the current Form, but it doesn't work on iOS.

Comment: iOS is one of the main reasons we have this thing. It's callback logic is indeed harder. Try re-showing it with `showModless()` and not `show()`. Within the `callSerially()`.

Comment: It's not working. The problem is that, on iOS, if inside `stop()` I save the Dialog in a `currentDialog` variable and then I invoke `dispose`, when the `start()` code is invoked the `currentDialog` variable has become `null` for reasons unknown to me.

Comment: I don't think we can make the currentDialog variable null without also making the currentForm variable null. It's possible you didn't assign a value to current form and so the right block of code didn't execute

Comment: Solved. I added the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63537825/1277576 with a full working test case.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason unknown to me, my previous attempts had failed. I finally found a code that solves the problem perfectly. I tested it successfully in the Simulator, on Android 10 and iOS 13. It's based on Shai's response https://stackoverflow.com/a/63321677/1277576.

```
public class MyApplication {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;
    private Dialog toBeRestored;

    public void init(Object context) {
        // use two network threads instead of one
        updateNetworkThreadCount(2);

        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature
        Log.bindCrashProtection(true);

        addNetworkErrorListener(err -> {
            // prevent the event from propagating
            err.consume();
            if (err.getError() != null) {
                Log.e(err.getError());
            }
            Log.sendLogAsync();
            Dialog.show("Connection Error", "There was a networking error in the connection to " + err.getConnectionRequest().getUrl(), "OK", null);
        });
    }

    public void start() {
        if (current != null) {
            current.show();
            if (toBeRestored != null) {
                CN.callSerially(() -> toBeRestored.show());
            }
            return;
        }
        Form hi = new Form("Persistent Dialog", BoxLayout.y());
        Button button = new Button("Open Dialog");
        hi.add(button);
        hi.show();

        button.addActionListener(l -> {
            Container dialogBody = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
            dialogBody.add(new SpanLabel("Dialog Body"));
            Dialog d = new Dialog(new BorderLayout()){
                @Override
                public void dispose() {
                    toBeRestored = this;
                    super.dispose();
                };
                
                @Override
                public void show() {
                    toBeRestored = null;
                    super.show();
                };
            };
            d.setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(false);
            d.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, dialogBody);
            Button okBtn = new Button("OK");
            d.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, FlowLayout.encloseCenter(okBtn));
            
            okBtn.addActionListener(ll -> {
                d.dispose();
            });
            
            d.show();
        });
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = getCurrentForm();
        if (current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog) current).dispose();
            current = getCurrentForm();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Comment: In this code every time you show the dialog (even without minimizing) it will be restored. You should set the dialog in the `stop()` method