# Lightweight Popup Dialogs on iOS

Tags: codenameone

After the PR https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/pull/3233, I get the popupDialogs as I want them (on Android). They are ok, the text is correctly in the centre, margin and padding are as I want them.

But I have an issue with iOS. Sometimes, when the popup Dialog contains very few text, iOS calculates wrong Dimension for the Dialog. It happens only on iOS.

What I understood is that the implementation of Dialog popups on iOS is native, while on Android it's lightweight. Please correct me if I have misunderstood. Since the Android implementation works well, I would like to use it on iOS as well. That's the meaning of this RFE of mine:
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3234

Anyway, I change my question: even without that RFE, can I use Lightweight Popup Dialogs also on iOS?

Comment: Another reason for this request is that the code https://stackoverflow.com/a/63537825/1277576, after restoring the app, does not show the popupDialog arrow on iOS, while it shows it on Android, proving that the lightweight implementation has fewer problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but it might be a bit tricky. If you use CSS setting the popup border becomes a huge pain because of [this issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3159).

So you'll need to either use the designer tool and define PopupDialog to explicitly use the `RoundRectBorder` or you'll need to do it from code (explicitly setting this into the theme).

A hack that might work (didn't try this) is using this code in your `init(Object)` instead of `initFirstTheme`:

```
try {
    theme = Resources.openLayered(resourceFile); 
    themeProps.put("PopupDialog.derive", "Dialog");
    themeProps.put("PopupDialog.border", RoundRectBorder.create().
            cornerRadius(2f).
            shadowOpacity(60).shadowSpread(3.0f));
    themeProps.put("PopupDialog.transparency", "255");
    themeProps.put("PopupDialog.bgColor", background);
    themeProps.put("PopupDialog.padding", "4,4,4,4");
    themeProps.put("PopupDialog.padUnit", new byte[]{Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS});
    UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(theme.getTheme(theme.getThemeResourceNames()[0]));
    Resources.setGlobalResources(theme);
} catch(IOException e){
    Log.e(e);
}
```

Comment: This hack is good (I've slightly customized it), it has the advantage of making popups working on iOS almost identical to Android: with this code, I don't need to use separate styling for Android and iOS anymore, moreover in most cases (but not all) popup sizing problems on iOS are solved. It's a good step forward, thanks.

Comment: On real Android and iOS devices the behavior is the desired one, in the sense that the differences between Android and iOS that I noticed in the Simulator are less evident: I confirm that this hack has solved some problems for me. Thanks again.